# NASM Segmentation Fault ( strchrnul )

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, nasm

Need help in a nasm code. Have to find if intgr1 mod intgr2==0, but cant use DIV. 
I am getting a segmentation fault. From gdb I found:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00007ffff7aacd2a in strchrnul () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

My program:

```
;nasm -f elf64 main.nasm
;gcc -o main main.o -lc


section .text
    global main
    extern scanf 
    extern printf

section .data
    request1: db "Dividendo: ", 0
    request2: db "Divisor: ", 0
    message1: db "Eh divisivel", 0
    message2: db "Nao eh divisivel", 0
    formatin: db "%d", 0
    intgr1: times 4 db 0 ; 32-bits integer = 4 bytes
    intgr2: times 4 db 0 ;

main:
    push request1   ;imprime pedido dividendo
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push intgr1 ;scanf do dividendo
    push formatin
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    push request2   ;imprime pedido divisor
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push intgr2 ;scanf do divisor
    push formatin
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    mov eax, [intgr1]   
    mov ebx, [intgr2]
    jmp L1

L1: cmp eax, ebx    ;compara dividendo divisor
    jb L2       ;se < entao vai pra l2
    sub eax,ebx ;dividendo:=dividendo-divisor
    jmp L1      ;vai pra L1

L2: cmp eax, 0  ;compara dividendo e 0
    je L3       ;se igual vai para l3
    jmp L4      ;se nao vai para l4

L3: push message1   ;imprime que eh divisivel
    call printf
    add esp, 4

L4:push message2    ;imprime que nao eh
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    MOV AL, 1   ;termina o programa
    MOV EBX, 0 
    INT 80h
```

Anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> nasm -f elf64 main.nasm

Your Assembling a 64bit app?  We don't push parameters in 64bit land, but pass in registers.

[Calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)  Look at the line in the table for `x86-64` it will tell you what registers Linux uses in its calling convention. `RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9, XMM0–7`

Your `printf` should be:

```
mov     rdi, request1
xor     rax, rax
call    printf
```

Your `printf` call needs a format parameter, or you can have problems in the future, learn the correct way now, and have less problems later.

Likewise, `scanf` is the same:

```
mov     rsi, intgr2
mov     rdi, formatin
xor     rax, rax
call    scanf
```

Since your linking with the C Library, you need to call `exit` so the library can do it's cleanup.

```
xor     rdi, rdi
call    exit
```

Comment: One may return from main instead of calling exit.